# How to hide a Direct3d window?

Tags: windows, window-manager

I want to hide a direct3d window (like a "bosskey program"). I have tryed some programs like 4t minimizer, but I cant...

Do you know some nice (maybe free?) program or script to accomplish this?

Comment: why not use alt-tab ?

Comment: maybe because alt+tab doesnt hide the window...

Comment: .... Winkey + D?

Comment: Winkey + D = "Show Desktop". i need hide (i.e. cannot be viewed)

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own custom hotkey scrip using the [**WinHide**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinHide.htm) function of [**AutoHotkey**](http://autohotkey.com). I have just tested this with some games running in DirectX mode.

e.g.

```
^y::WinHide,Counter-Strike,
^g::WinShow,Counter-Strike,
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> to hide, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> to show.

Comment: +1 - If it can't be done with ahk, it can't be done at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Elongsoft's [Hide Window Hotkey 3.1](http://www.elongsoft.com/hidewindow/hidewindow.htm). I use it with debugging adobe air applications. Its nice because it can hide a window by changing its alpha transparency rather than other applications that try to remove instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> for "Minimize all", perhaps?